# Visual Studio csproj structure - compile element contains reference to a deleted file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have deleted a class in my solution.
The csproj file still holds a reference to it.

as follows

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile.. >
    <Compile Include="MyPath\MyDeletedFile.cs" />
    <Compile.. >
</ItemGroup>
```

Why wasnt this fle removed?
How do I remove it? 
Thanks.

Comment: You're looking at this, presumably, in some form of text editor? I'm confused how you're not aware of how to remove it.

Comment: I did remove it. I just think it is a bug, and wondered is there a safer way to remove it.

Comment: There's no real way for us to fathom out how or why it didn't get removed as you expected. But editing the file is a perfectly legitimate way  to fix the problem - it's why the project files are in XML after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the line from the csproject file. That should do the magic

Comment: Yes, well, already did. Just wondered if there is a solution that will safely remove it from the VS

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Project  select **"unload project"**

Right click on Project select **"edit"**
... hack away...

Right click on Project select **"Reload"**